# Using "Endpoint Must Be Covered By" topology rule?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology

ArcMap 10.5.1 
Windows 7 SP 1

Creating a drainage network. All runs of pipe are straight, and therefore must be capped on either end with a structure. So, I created a new GDB, FDS, and a set of topology rules.

[image: data structure]

Here's the issue: When I go to set up the topology (using the wizard in ArcCatalog), I am unable to select my point datasets from the list of "feature classes that will participate in the topology":

[image: topology wizard]

Comment: That is weird, a feature class should only be excluded if it already participates in a topology or geometric network, I think your database is going bad, try exporting it to XML workspace (with data), create a new file geodatabase and import the XML workspace; this action is fairly drastic but usually rectifies a bad database.

Comment: I have seen this at least once, but not sure exactly what caused it, which usually means I just went back later and the problem had disappeared  A possible reason is that your points have Z and M values enabled; they might also be  locked or damaged  in some way.